# src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tns:callResult' to a(n) 'type definition'

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, xsd

in Spring boot, when I want to write the xsd file (I'm writing this for calling webservice) I get error for type.(src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'tns:callResult' to a(n) 'type definition')

```
<xs:element name="releaseMsisdnResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="callResult" type="tns:callResult"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

How should I fix this?
tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

`tns` means `Target Namespace`, which is the current document.
You need to provide another `element` named `callResult`, e.g.

```
<xs:element name="callResult">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ... />
      ...
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```